# Mechanism for Ce(IV) Oxidation of Naphthalene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-oxidation

S. Cotton's *Lanthanide and Actinide Chemistry* reports that naphthalene can be oxidized to naphthalene-1,4-dione using cerric ammonium sulfate (CAS), $\ce{MeCN, H2SO4},$ and $\ce{H2O}$.<sup>1</sup> No mechanism was provided, and I was unable to find a complete mechanism for this transformation in the literature. From what I did find, Love *et al.*<sup>2</sup> have reported the first step of this mechanism is the formation of the radical cation while the second step is the attack of a water molecule. After these two steps, the authors of the paper do not give any further information. I proposed a mechanism below, but I have a few concerns. To start, why is sulfuric acid used when protons seem to be lost during the transformation? I assume this is to prevent the cerium from reacting with the water to form hydroxides as it can be quite basic, but it is nonetheless unsettling.

[image: CAS Oxidation of Naphthalene by CAS]

---

**References:**

<sup>1</sup>Simon Cotton, In *Lanthanide and Actinide Chemistry*;  Inorganic Chemistry, A Wiley Textbook Series, John Wiley & Sons, Ltd: Chichester, England, 2006 (ISBN-13: 978-0-470-01005-1).

<sup>2</sup>Brian E. Love, Alexander L. Simmons, "Substituent Effects in the Oxidation of 2-Alkyl-1,4-dialkoxybenzenes with Ceric Ammonium Nitrate," *Tetrahedron Lett.* **2016**, 57(50), 5712-5715 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2016.11.042).